# Regex extract positive or negative number from string oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I am struggling in finding the solution to the following problem:

Assuming the **character** values 512a, -1230b, -2 and 2.
Which can be obtained into a table from the following query:

```
with my_input_values as (
select '512a' my_val from dual union select '-1230b' my_val from dual union select '2' my_val from dual union select '-2' my_val  from dual
) 
select * from my_input_values;
```

I am trying to build the regular expression that extract the number keeping the positive or negative sign from each value.

The expected result are the following numeric values: 512, -1230, 2 and -2.
Which can be obtained into a table through the following query:

```
with result as (
    select 512 my_val from dual union select -1230 my_val from dual union select 2 my_val from dual union select -2 my_val from dual
)
select * from result;
```

Comment: I don't understand. Does the first code block above represent an SQL statement or a text string?

Comment: Clearly an sql statement to obtain the values on your pc

Comment: Are your numbers integers?

Comment: Presumably the expected results are `512`, `-1230` and `2`, not the whole union query? Also, is the pattern always at the start of the string, or could it be for example `blahblah512bananas` or `abc-xyz-whatever42`?

Comment: I presented a reproducible example, hence, this is the only pattern. However, @Thefourhbird answer works in any case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match an optional character (or use an asterix `*` instead of `?` to match zero or more characters) followed by a quote. Then you could replace that match with an empty string.

[`[a-z]?'`](https://regex101.com/r/B7Zbuq/1)

Comment: Cool solution because it removes all alphabetic characters from the string, regardless the order!

Comment: I just noticed that it does not exclude uppercase characters. How can I change it in such a way it considers both lower and upper case characters?

Comment: You could use `[a-zA-Z]?'`

Comment: You could use `[a-zA-Z]?'`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness of the answer, the Oracle code to accomplish this task is the following:

```
select regexp_replace('-asd51assaddasd2a', '[a-z]?') from dual;
```

which successfully results in a numberic field maintaining the polarity sign

```
select -512 from dual;
```

Comment: It should be `select regexp_replace(..., '[a-z]?''') from dual;` according to your question.

Comment: Why do I have to add '' after the ?'

Comment: '-1230b': the single quote are necessary to tell oracle that -1230b is a character and not a numeric column named "b" valorized -1230